# Embedding album art in m4a files?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, batch, aac, m4a

I have a directory of m4a files together with a single album art image named `cover.jpg`. How can I 'embed' this album art image *into* the m4a files using the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use AtomicParsley and a bash 'for' loop. Install AtomicParsley on *any* version of Ubuntu as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install atomicparsley
```

Then change to the directory containing the m4a files and run the following:

```
for i in *.m4a
do
AtomicParsley "$i" --artwork cover.jpg --overWrite 
done
```

And now your m4a files have the album art embedded and you can safely delete your album art image. This will work for *all* versions of Ubuntu...

Answer (score 2):

Covers can be added with the [TagEditor project](//github.com/Martchus/tageditor):

```
tageditor -s cover=ju.jpg --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```

To remove:

```
tageditor -s cover= --max-padding 100000 -f ki.m4a
```