# LAME alternative for .webm and .m4a files

Tags: sound, music, webm, m4a, lame

[Lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) utility is available for attaching image files as cover to mp3 audio files. However, it does seem to not work for webm and m4a formats, yielding such an error:

```
Warning: unsupported audio format
```

Is there any workaround for this, or possibly alternatives suitable for m4a and webm files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. I am not seeing what this has to do with the unspecified version of Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Your solution for m4a is reported here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/809175/embedding-album-art-in-m4a-files